How to fix the blank page while deploying my project on vercel
i  deployed my project in vercel it show an blank page when run  on the local it is working but when it deployed on vercel it show only blank white page https://github.com/manibalaji003/Weather-App.git this is my repo
after the deployment it show error in the console
*GET
https://weather-gjuianb7g-manibalaji003s-projects.vercel.app/Weather-App/assets/index-CUu_arT8.js
GET
https://weather-gjuianb7g-manibalaji003s-projects.vercel.app/Weather-App/assets/index-CGxSqi-R.css
[HTTP/2 404  67ms]
Loading module from “https://weather-gjuianb7g-manibalaji003s-projects.vercel.app/Weather-App/assets/index-CUu_arT8.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/plain”)*

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
